# How can I avoid getting duplicate name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I avoid getting duplicate names? I already tried different things, but all of them dont work

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '') 
     FROM 1  
     FOR POSITION(',' IN GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '' )))-1))) AS lastname,
    organisation.keywords AS keywords
FROM 
    obj_resource resource
LEFT JOIN  
    rel_raci resource_raci  ON resource.ID = resource_raci.PERSON_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    obj_resource organisation on  organisation.ID =  resource_raci.OBJ_ID
 -- Gibt nur die markierten Massnahmen aus
WHERE 
    CONTAINS('463bb931:158af3df8f6:1d97', resource.id, -1)
```

Results:

```
 Volkert    
 Volkert    
 Vogel  
 Vogel  
 Vasiliadou 
 Vasiliadou 
 Von Aesch  DGI-PVB
 Von Aesch  DGI-PFR
 Von Aesch  DGI-PBD
 Von Aesch  DGI-PBP
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is not a sql-server function. Please tag your question correctly, without products that are not involved.

Comment: `group by lastname`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Mybe :)

Comment: It is still a duplicate

Comment: DhruvJoshi why edit the tags of a question when OP has not stated otherwise? @ana please edit the tags to be correct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a. lastname , a.keywords from
(SELECT 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '') 
     FROM 1  
     FOR POSITION(',' IN GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '' )))-1))) AS lastname,
    organisation.keywords AS keywords
FROM 
    obj_resource resource
LEFT JOIN  
    rel_raci resource_raci  ON resource.ID = resource_raci.PERSON_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    obj_resource organisation on  organisation.ID =  resource_raci.OBJ_ID
 -- Gibt nur die markierten Massnahmen aus
WHERE 
    CONTAINS('463bb931:158af3df8f6:1d97', resource.id, -1)) a
group by a.lastname, a.keywords
```

Comment: its not working. somehow i need to group the keywords togehter, so the lastname is not duplicate. I dont know how

Comment: @ana are you still getting the duplicates or some error?

Comment: @ana well that is weird, I changed the query. Can u try?

Comment: I should group all names together how can I do this?

Comment: @ana what do u mean by all names? you have only two columns right? `lastname` and `keywords`.

Comment: yes i mean the lastnames are duplicate, it shouldnt be

Comment: @ana are u on sql-server? IMHO sql-server doesn't support `group_concat`

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` may need to be repositioned so it occurs right after the `SELECT`.  In the question you have it inside a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT (SUBSTRING(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '') 
     FROM 1  
     FOR POSITION(',' IN GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '' )))-1))) AS lastname,
    organisation.keywords AS keywords
FROM 
    obj_resource resource
LEFT JOIN  
    rel_raci resource_raci  ON resource.ID = resource_raci.PERSON_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    obj_resource organisation on  organisation.ID =  resource_raci.OBJ_ID
 -- Gibt nur die markierten Massnahmen aus
WHERE 
    CONTAINS('463bb931:158af3df8f6:1d97', resource.id, -1)
```